# Probability of Snow in New York

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In New York, snow is reported 25% of days in February.  If this trend continues, what is the probability that it will snow exactly 9 days this coming February and is not a leap year?

Solve this problem by using 
First)  The approximation of the binomial distribution 
Second) The Binomial Distribution

How would I apply the Binomial Distribution and approximate distribution? I am having difficulty extracting the info from the problem.

So far I have the following
p = .25
q = .75
n = 28 days
k = 9

Would I apply that to C(n,k)(p^k)(q^n-k)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes.** Under the assumption that the binomial distribution is applicable (i.e. it snows on each day in February with probability $25\%$, independent of other days) the probability of exactly $9$ days with snow is
$$ \binom{28}{9} (.25)^9 (.75)^{19}. $$
There are $\binom{28}{9}$ ways to choose the $9$ days, the probability that is does snow on these days is $.25^9$ and the probability that it does not snow on all other days is $.75^{19}$.

Comment: They way your worded "i.e. it snows on each day in February with probability 25%, independent of other days" makes things more readable. I interpreted as 7 days of February snows. That is why i was so lost in this question.

Comment: There is a problem with this answer.  Suppose out of $25$% it reportedly snows in Feb that it always snows on Feb 29th.  That would mean that when Feb has only $28$ days that it will actually be LESS than $25$% chance of snow on those days because it is being averaged in with the $29$ day Feb over periods of years (I would assume).  Therefore the answer here is only an approximation because you didn't state that it snows $25$% in Feb on random days.

Comment: I believe the assumption that there is a 25% probability of snow on each day of February (whether it is Feb 29th or not) is clearly stated.

Comment: My interpretation of the question is that over time, it is reported that it snows 25% of the days in February.  It didn't state which days.  My statement that Feb 29th could be a particular heavy snow day is valid, thus slightly skewing the probability of snow on the 28 day Febs.  For example, if over a 20 year period, it was observed that it always snowed on Feb 29th, that would factor into the 25% for Feb but then in 28 day Febs, since there is no Feb 29th, that month would actually have LESS than a 25% chance of snow each day (on average).  Feb was a "bad" month to pick for this question.

Answer (score -2):

But in reality this answer is not accurate because snow on each day is not independent of other days.  For example, it may start snowing at 11:30PM on Feb 1st so that would likely increase the chance that it would snow on Feb 2nd (right after midnight for example).  So the days are NOT independent of each other.

For things like randomly drawn cards and fair coin tosses, calculating probability is meaningful.  For this weather problem, it is only an estimate at best because of the problem stated above, and because past weather is not an assurance of future weather.

Comment: I forgot to right in Assuming independence. But thank you for the insight if it was a real world scenario

Comment: In a situation like this it is unrealistic to assume independence.  That is what is frustrating to me about certain math word problems is they make unreasonable assumptions.